# How can I exclude some unused images from lint in Android Studio using the lint.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

I have a large amount of images in my `drawable-xhdpi` folder that show up as unused when I run lint. These files are referenced dynamically at runtime and, therefore, have no static references.

I'd like to configure my `lint.xml` so that these files are excluded from lint. I've added an XML at the module directory (not the top-level project directory but the module directory) with the necessary directives but I still can't get lint to ignore them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress XmlUnboundNsPrefix -->
<lint>
    <issue id="AndroidLintUnusedResources">
        <ignore path="res/drawable-xhdpi/i0.png" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Comment: Might be late answer but please checkout Iaalto's answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896452/android-studio-lint-xml-configuration

Answer (score 3):

If you reference the images only dynamically and if they are only in one size (`drawable-xhdpi`), it might be a good idea to put them into `assets` instead of `res`.

Otherwise, try setting `path="**/res/drawable-xhdpi/i0.png"`.

Also, the **issue id** that worked for me was `id="UnusedResources"` instead of `id="AndroidLintUnusedResources"`

Remember to put reference to `lint.xml` in your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file('lint.xml')
    }
}
```

In this case, `lint.xml` and `build.gradle` are placed in the same directory.