# Android Studio lint.xml configuration

Tags: android, xml, lint

I would like to configure lint in Android Studio to ignore some file. I have placed the *lint.xml* file in *app/* folder. Here is the content of the lint file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="UnusedResources">
        <ignore path="res/drawable/background_palette_drawable_6.xml" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

When I run lint to check for unused resources it still finds this file as unused.

In app *build.gradle* I have:

```groovy
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    abortOnError false
    absolutePaths false
    lintConfig file('lint.xml')
}
```

I have tried changing the file path to `/app/src/main/res/drawable/background_palette_drawable_6.xml`
and still it does not work.

I put `<issue id="UnusedResources" severity="ignore">` and in that case it just **ignores** all the unused resources so it seems the file `lint.xml` is found correctly but maybe something is wrong with the path?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider using `path="**/background_palette_drawable_6.xml"` with the `**` glob pattern to match the file regardless of its location.